# Umbraco's useage of Tempdata

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco, load-balancing

On inspection of the Umbraco source code, I've noticed alot of useage of TempData and this worries me. If I choose to host my site in a web farm that does not have sticky sessions enabled, won't everything Umbraco stored in TempData be gone? Has anyone had issues with this in a similar environment, or even a cloud-based solution?

This is in regards to Umbraco v6.1.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you set up your instances of Umbraco. I have just set a load-balanced website using Umbraco, and although the published website is load-balanced, the Umbraco back office isn't. This is mainly because it doesn't need to be.

You would load-balance an application if the traffic was going to be high enough to warrant it, but with the Umbraco back-office, it's possibly unlikely that it is going to have that load of traffic.

Check [this article](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/install-and-setup/installing-umbraco-for-load-balanced-environments) out, it explains some of the options available.

I set up the published site to be loadbalanced across two servers. Both instances of the published site resolve against a primary domain (www.site.com), but each instance has a unique, non-loadbalanced sub domain (u1.site.com and u2.site.com). The back office has it's own subdomain (admin.site.com) and the Umbraco directory of the public facing site is disabled using IIS's URL restrictions.

This way I can ensure that the back office isn't load-balanced, whilst the published site is. The back office can also then make distributed publishing calls to the u1 and u2 subdomains.

Comment: So if I'm understanding you correctly then your site is working because Umbraco's useage of TempData (which can be seen in their source code) is only for the back office and therefore doesn't matter because you've got this setup as a single instance?

Comment: Yes that's correct. Every time someone accesses the back office, it's as a single instance.